# Prove this exercise from K.L. Chung using just Borel Cantelli Lemma

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Prove that probability of convergence of sequence of independent r.v. is either $0$ or $1$.

Proving the convergence is $0$ is straightforward, using **B-C lemma**. But for proving it to be $1$, we need events to be independent. So can someone prove that part.

This is given as exercise in K.L. Chung book after explaining and proving different versions of Borel-Cantelli lemma, so please don't use **Kolmogorov 0-1 Law**

We can do this by defining set 
$A_k = \{|X_m - X_n| < \epsilon \text{ for all } m>n \ge k\}$ 
and then if $\sum P(A_k) < \infty$ then $P(A_k io)=0$. But, the trouble if $\sum P(A_k) = \infty$ then we can't claim that $P(A_k io)=1$ as $A_k$ need not be independent for different $k$.

Comment: "Proving the [probability of] convergence is $0$ is straightforward". Huh? It's impossible to prove it's $0$, since it may be $1$. If you _could_ prove it was $0$ that would show it  was $0$ or $1$ and you'd be done....

Comment: @David C. Ullrich  I didn't get your comment, but I have made my question more clear.

Comment: Let me try again. You say proving the probabillity of convergence is $0$ is straightforward.  If so then you're done (because $p=0$ certainly implies $p=0$ or  $p=1$). Exactly how do you prove the probability of convergence if $0$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(E_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of independant events. If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(E_n)<\infty$, you already showed that the probability of an infinite number of events happening is zero. Now, if instead $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(E_n)=\infty$, we try to show that the probability of an infinite number of events happening is one.

We have that $1-\mathbb{P}(\limsup_{n\to\infty}E_n)=\mathbb{P}(\liminf_{n\to\infty}E_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{j=n}^\infty E_j^c)$. Because the events are independent, the probability of any of them happening at the same time is the product of their probabilities, i.e.
$$\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{j=n}^\infty E_j^c) = \prod_{j=n}^\infty (1-\mathbb{P}(E_j)).$$

Now here's a trick: because $1-x$ is always less than or equal to $e^{-x}$ for $x\in[0,1]$ (see Taylor expansion), we have that $\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{j=n}^\infty E_j^c) \leq \prod_{j=n}^\infty e^{-\mathbb{P}(E_j)}=\exp{(-\sum_{j=n}^\infty}\mathbb{P}(E_j))=0$. Therefore $\mathbb{P}(\limsup_{n\to\infty}E_n)=1$.

Comment: This is just partial converse of Borel Canteli lemma. Using this how can we prove that probability  that sequence of independent rv will converge is 1.

Comment: What does it mean for a sequence of independent r.v. to converge?

Comment: I have updated my question by adding few more lines. Can you show that the events I have defined by $A_k$  are independent ?